# Node peerDependencies Errors With Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm having problems using grunt on a new project that I was asked to work on. When I run:

```
npm install
```

in my project directory I get a bunch of peerinvalid errors, like this:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.4.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jasmine@0.6.5 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
```

etc..

When I run:

```
grunt --version
```

I get:

```
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.4
```

I've been googling and messing around for a long time with no luck. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what grunt@~0.4.0 means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `package.json` may contain a dependency to a fixed version of grunt. Try to define:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.0",
  }
```

or with an old version of npm:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0",
  }
```

(see [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) for an explanation of differences between `~` and `^`)

`peerDependencies` is used by grunt plugins to specify which version of grunt they needs. `~0.4.0` means about the version `0.4` and is equivalent to `0.4.x`

Comment: thanks, package.json does contain  "grunt": "^0.4.4", I tried changing it to ~0.4.4, but it still doesn't work... any ideas why that might be?

Comment: did you try to remove the node_modules folder and run again `npm install` ?

Comment: try to change `^0.4.4` by `^0.4.0`

Comment: @krampstudio maybe you can complete your response with the versions of non you had in mind